# how to remove android device from google dashboard

Tags: android

Is there any way to remove android device from Google Dashboard? Unfortunately, right now I don't have the specified device. I signed in using my gmail account in that device but unable to remove my gmail account from that device.

Comment: just change your gmail password,so that on that device no one can use your mail this is what is your problem i think

Comment: thank you praveen, you are right i have already changed my password. But thing is Google Dashboard is still showing me that device.i.e. I am still registered with device and using that device.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not possible to remove an account from Gmail , if once it is added ! You have to go for a Factory Data Reset option which would remove all your data from you device !!

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want to remove the signed in account from the device? Then go to accounts and sync  and remove the signed in account from there. Also you could restore you device using factory restore settings which makes all data vanish.

Comment: But i don't have device and that is why i want to remove from google dashboard